# Uninstall ubuntu and install it again along with windows

Tags: uninstall, system-installation, format

I use Ubuntu 12.04LTS and now I want to format my laptop and then make two OS get installed:-

1. Windows 7 or Windows 8.
2. Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

Please tell me  step by step way to do the same.

I am having problem basically during uninstalling the Ubuntu as I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Actually I want a dual boot system with Windows 7/8 and Ubuntu. My vendor did not partitioned my HDD and installed Ubuntu directly. I want to partition my HDD too. That's why I am thinking about formatting. Is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to uninstall Ubuntu and then install it again? It seems unnecessary. I would do this:

- `sudo apt-get install gparted`, then run `sudo gparted`. Create free space for Windows by resizing your Linux partition(s) as suitable. (This step is unnecessary if Windows is installed on its own, separate physical drive).
- Boot Windows and install into the free space, creating an NTFS partition in the Windows setup. Restart your computer. Only Windows will start, because Windows doesn't care about other OS:es and won't bother to look for them.
- Install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) in Windows to modify your BCD as suitable, add your Linux installation and set it as default if you wish. This step can be replaced by "repairing" or reinstalling GRUB. It's up to you how you choose to solve it, I prefer EasyBCD as it seems easier to just leave Windows boot menu in place. I usually set a very short timeout (2-3 seconds) as you will get a second menu afterwards with GRUB, that actually **does** detect Windows, so you can get back to the first menu if you wish anyway. Of course, one could argue that it's cleaner to just fix GRUB. To each his/her own.
- If you choose to use EasyBCD, restart your computer when done and you should get a Windows-like menu asking you what OS to boot, both of them should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install windows with an existing Ubuntu,

- create a new partition by re-sizing you partition using Gparted in
  Ubuntu
- Format it as ntfs.
- Now boot with windows installation disk and install it on newly created partition.
- You will need to reinstall GRUB after installing window. Here is how
  reinstall GRUB. [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

.

.

Comment: The end result of this would be Windows booting instantly without giving you a choice, as Windows does not look for alternate operating systems on install.

Comment: Ok i have edited it.

Answer (score -1):

Just install the windows 7/8 normally and than install ubuntu 12.04 by using ubuntu windows installer.
Watch this video.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqNqOrWkhOM&list=PLjnOm_giI__5mtLIAzk3KyzNOBfZblo2b&index=2